# Github : Accidentally started working upon the `Downloaded` zip of the repository instead of the `clone`

Tags: git, github

I accidentally started working upon a downloaded archive of my repository instead of the Git clone and I realised this only after already making changes.

How can I commit these changes to my original repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're working in `<dir1>`:

Clone the repository in another directory:

```
cd ../
git clone <url> <dir2>
```

Move the `.git` directory to where you were working on and then clean up the cloned copy:

```
mv <dir2>/.git <dir1>
rm -rf <dir2>
```

Any changes you have made will show up with `git status`.

Answer (score 1):

Clone the repository afresh, and move and replace files from your zipped folder to the cloned repo. That way, the `.git` folder within the cloned repo stays in tact, while your changes replace the original files. So, the changed code will start appearing in `git status` etc.

PS: create a backup of the zipped folder before you proceed.